# Loading jQuery plugin defaults from the server (AJAX)

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Im working on a private jQuery plugin in the following format:

```
    (function( $ ){
      var defaults = {};

      $.fn.cmFlex = function(opts) {

        this.each(function() {
            //Element specific options
            var o = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);

            //Code here
        });

        //code Here
      };
    })( jQuery );
```

How will i go on loading the default options from the server before $.cmFlex() is first called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://my.domain.com/prefsUrl?callback=?", function(defaults){
      $.fn.cmFlex = function(opts) {

        this.each(function() {
            //Element specific options
            var o = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);

            //Code here
        });

        //code Here
      };
});
```

Assuming prefsUrl returns a valid JSONP response.  If you're unfamiliar with JSONP, I suggest you google it.

Comment: the problem with this, is that the function will not be available until the request is completed, and you don't have any declarative method (except for looping asking for `typeOf($.cmFlex)`).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- **Quick n' dirty, and 'secure' option:** Make a synchronous call to the server. You can set up an ajax object to lock down the browser until it gets the answer. There's an option in jQuery's Ajax methods called `async`, which is by default set to true. If you change this to false, the JS execution flow will hang until you get the answer from the server. It's not a really good solution, because if your server is down, or the generation of those global variables is a long process, you'll have the user waiting for it.
- **Cleaner but 'insecure' option:** in the first call to `cmFlex`, check if `defaults` is `null`. If it is, call to the Ajax method to fill it, and put a callback function that does the `cmFlex` function. The problem here is, that if it's called again before it get the default values, you'll be doing a duplicate call to the server.
- **Clean and secure option:** put a flag in your object, something like `isLoaded`, and if the user calls to `cmFlex` by second time, and this flag is set to `false`, raise an exception, or handle it adding this call to a queue.

Good luck!